# Query plan changes at runtime in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, sql-tuning

I've two simple tables:

```
Profile (20M entries)
----------------------------
pId | fail 
123 | 0
234 | 2
345 | 0

Work (50M entries)
-----------------
pId
123
234
123
345
123
345
```

I just want to mark `fail` as `1` in `Profile` table for entries that have above threshold `pId` entries in `Work` table. `pId` in `Profile` table is indexed and I don't want to touch rows where `fail` is not `0`.

The query I'm using right now is:

```
UPDATE Profile 
SET fail = 1 
WHERE pId IN 
    (
      SELECT pId 
      FROM Work 
      GROUP BY pId 
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
    )
AND Profile.fail = 0;
```

In pgAdmin, I get explain plan as below:

```
"Update on Profile a  (cost=1134492.79..1559750.23 rows=5180 width=1014)"
"  ->  Hash Join  (cost=1134492.79..1559750.23 rows=5180 width=1014)"
"        Hash Cond: (a.pId = b.pId)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on Profile a  (cost=0.00..425216.00 rows=15462 width=976)"
"              Filter: (fail = 0)"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=1134491.95..1134491.95 rows=67 width=32)"
"              ->  Subquery Scan on b  (cost=1134488.78..1134491.95 rows=67 width=32)"
"                    ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1134488.78..1134491.28 rows=67 width=4)"
"                          Group Key: Work.pId"
"                          Filter: (count(*) > 5)"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on Work  (cost=0.00..894341.52 rows=48029452 width=4)"
```

It takes couple of minutes to run.

Now when these two tables are created at runtime with the same data, the query plan changes to:

```
"Update on Profile  (cost=1250747.42..1251317.47 rows=67 width=386)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1250747.42..1251317.47 rows=67 width=386)"
"        ->  Subquery Scan on "ANY_subquery"  (cost=1250746.98..1250750.15 rows=67 width=32)"
"              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1250746.98..1250749.48 rows=67 width=4)"
"                    Group Key: Work.pId"
"                    Filter: (count(*) > 5)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on Work  (cost=0.00..985990.32 rows=52951332 width=4)"
"        ->  Index Scan using Profile_idx on Profile  (cost=0.44..8.46 rows=1 width=348)"
"              Index Cond: (pId = "ANY_subquery".pId)"
"              Filter: (fail = 0)"
```

Which takes an hour to run. I've even tried switching from subquery to a join, but it's still producing the same result. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Firstly `WHERE pId IN (subquery)` can be horribly slow if there are a lot of results in the subquery. If there are a moderate amount of results (probably no more than a hundred or so, but this is just a vague idea) then performance can improve massively by using an array: `WHERE pId = ANY(ARRAY(subquery))`. Often the query planner will perform the `IN` to `ARRAY` conversion automatically but sometimes not and it has to be done explicitly.

Comment: @404 thank you for your comment. I've around 20M rows returned in the inner query. Let me try using `ANY(ARRARY(subquery))` and get back to you.

Comment: Yikes! I wouldn't bother with an array in that case. Try this and see what the performance is like: `UPDATE profile p SET ... WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM work w WHERE w.pid = p.pid) > 2 AND fail = 0`, it may be faster to calculate the count for each row on the fly which will hopefully use the index on `work`, rather than create a result set of 20 million rows and then compare each `profile` row against this unindexed result set.

Comment: `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for both queries would help. Did you run `ANALYZE` after creating the table?

Comment: I did correlate the tables but it was taking even more time. Let me try once more. @Laurenz no, I didn't, let me try that.

Comment: @Laurenz `ANALYZE` on both tables did help and changed the whole query plan. The query ran in 3 minutes, but `ANALYZE` on both tables took more than 12 minutes. Can I do anything about that?

Comment: What is your `default_statistics_target` setting? The higher, the more work `ANALYZE` has to do.

Comment: @Laurenz I've not set `default_statistics_target` explicitly. I'm not sure what should be the minimum value for my planner to choose the optimized plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to your problem probably is:

> Now when these two tables are created at runtime with the same data, the query plan changes to [the worse]

PostgreSQL automatically collects table statistics, but it takes a short while for autoanalyze to kick in.

All queries that run between the bulk data modification and the time that autoanalyze finishes will be likely to have bad execution plans.

It is a good idea to explicitly run `ANALYZE` on the tables at the end off mass data modifications.

Comment: If I turn off nested loops and hash joins, the query runs in 4 mins. Is that something I should do before running the query and turn them on after the query is finished?

Comment: That would be a last resort; I am sure you can do better. If you add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output to the question, we might get a clue.

Comment: The query has been running from the last 3 hours and still not finished, so hard to get the `analyze, buffers`. But after your suggestion, I've set statistics to 25 which seems to pick the right query plan and only takes a minute to analyze. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I understand. Then it would help to get `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT pId  FROM Work GROUP BY pId HAVING COUNT(*) > 2;`, because that is probably where the problem is. Relying on a misestimate caused by low quality statistics to accidentally fix the problem is kind of fragile.